# Can I tie down ski/snow board to my roof rack like a canoe?

Tags: skiing, cross-country-skiing, snowboarding

I have raised cross bar on my SUV roof as the image shows:
[image: car roof]
I also got a couple 15ft. long Thule ratchet straps for tie-down canoes.

Now my question is, can I tie down ski and snowboards on the roof without a ski holder? How safe is it on high way? Any good setup examples?

Any instruction or tip is welcome. I am not skiing enthusiast so I prefer not to invest in a ski holder.

Comment: Is it not possible to carry the skis inside the car? If I don't have access to a roof box, I carry them inside. I just don't like the idea of road salt and general moisture plus high airflow affecting my skis for hours.

Comment: Cross country ski can be a little long given I am 200lbs......Road salt I will wipe but moisture and airflow should be everyday business that a ski should handle. Personal opinion.

Comment: Good enough explanation. I had downhill skiing in mind where carbon steel edges suffer much more easily from road conditions than XC skis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this should work. You may want to pad your roof rack so they don't scratch each other and make sure they are strapped tightly but other than that it should work fine.

Just orientate them in line with the vehicle and make sure the straps are tight.

Comment: I think I can whoop something up with leather or foam pad for padding. Any "standard" strap pattern for advice? Did not find much(any) online.

Comment: @Bogdan I don't know if there is a stand way, I would just do a couple of loops